# Knockout.js callback whenever a component is loaded into the DOM

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm writing a single page app using knockout.js. I want to make all textboxes in the application behave in a certain manner, e.g. selecting all current text on focus.

In order to avoid repetitive solutions such as adding a custom binding to all input fields, or implementing afterRender everywhere I load a component/template, I want to solve this at a centralized location, e.g handling a global event etc.

My first hunch was to implement a custom component loader, and the following code works **the first time a component is loaded**, but not so much for consecutive load. However it should provide a good exapmle of what I am trying to do

Summary: The event binding to `focusHandler` in the provided code is the code that I want to run whenever a component has been rendered by knockout. I want to avoid having to specify this everywhere I load a **component or template**.

```
var callbackHandle: number;
var focusHandler = (e: JQueryEventObject) => {
    var $this = $(e.target);

    $this.select();

    window.setTimeout(() => {
        $this.select();
    }, 1);

    // Work around WebKit's little problem
    function mouseUpHandler() {
        // Prevent further mouseup intervention
        $this.off("mouseup", mouseUpHandler);
        return false;
    }

    $this.mouseup(mouseUpHandler);
};
var templateAutoSelectInputTextLoader = {
    loadTemplate: (name, templateConfig, callback) => {

        var internalCallback = (data: any) => {
            callback(data);
            // Throttling so that this only happens once (after all components are loaded)
            if (callbackHandle) {
                clearTimeout(callbackHandle);
            }

            callbackHandle = window.setTimeout(() => {
                $("input[type=text]").off("focus", focusHandler).on("focus", focusHandler);
                console.log("Components loaded");
            }, 200);

        };

        ko.components.defaultLoader.loadTemplate(name, templateConfig, internalCallback);
    }
};

ko.components.loaders.unshift(templateAutoSelectInputTextLoader);
```

Comment: You said "In order to avoid repetitive solutions such as adding a custom binding to all input fields". You can use jquery On() to handle all inputs, and it need to be declared just once. Does it solve you problem?

Comment: Problem is that this is a single page application where the page is loaded only once from the server, however the DOM is dynamically modifield throughout the lifecycle of the application. $(...).on(...) will only apply to the elements currently in the DOM. The challenge is to do this binding at the apropriate time, i.e. when an input field has actually been loaded into the DOM

Comment: Use delegated events to attach event handlers. Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. The document element is available in the head of the document before loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without waiting for the document to be ready.

Comment: In that case, you can use `$('body').on('focus', 'input[type="text"]', function (){ });`

Comment: Wonderful! Feel free to post this as an answer too, so I can give you some well deserved points :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is an SPA, the page is dynamically modified all the time. However, the `body`element is created just once, right? You can use delegated events attached to `body`.

```
$('body').on('focus', 'input[type="text"]', function (){
   //your function here
});
```